# Should I pass a large List<int> by reference or by value?

Tags: c#

```
List<int> Integers = new List<int>();

SomeMethod1(ref Integers);
SomeMethod2(Integers);
```

We are using large lists, and were wondering what is more efficient?
If Call-By-Value copies the whole list, we assume Call-By-Reference is the most efficient? Is this true?

Comment: Why don't you just test it yourself with 1.000.000 iterations and a `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Other than performance, do you realize they are different on functionality side? On the other hand, [race your hourses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: As List<> is a reference type, calling by value does not copy the entire list. Only the reference to it.

Comment: Now would be a good time to read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Last I checked `List<T>` was a reference type.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight...I agree, this is a legit question.  Some users are way to quick to downvote.  SO is about helping people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is C#, not C++. `List<T>` is a by-reference type, so in both cases no copying will be done.

The only difference is that in the first case `SomeMethod1` will be able to modify `Integers` variable in the caller, for example, by setting a different list object into it

```
void SomeMethod1(ref List<int> list) {
    list = new [] {1, 2, 3}.ToList(); // Modifies Integers in the caller
}
```

while `SomeMethod2` would not be able to modify the variable (but it would be able to modify the list).

```
void SomeMethod2(List<int> list) {
    list.Add(123); // Modifies the list passed as Integers
    list = new [] {1, 2, 3}.ToList(); // Integers in the caller references the old list
}
```

Therefore, the thing that should drive your choice of parameter passing mechanism for `List<int>` is whether or not you wish `SomeMethodX` to be able to modify the variable in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Since `List<>` is a `class`, using your second method also pass the object as reference.

On the opposite, that would be a different scenario if your collection was a `struct`. A structure is passed by value by default. Thus, the keyword `ref` would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `SomeMethod()` would want to read or *modify* (not replace) the list, e.g. by adding or removing elements from it; both would work equally fine using ref or not. In no case will the wole list be copied; the normal call (without ref) would copy the *reference* (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes), while the ref call would copy a pointer to that reference (same size).

Using ref indicates that you want to change what the caller's reference points to by replacing the whole list object with an entirely new list. That is entirely possible but not entirely typical. If you don't actually want to replace the original list the ref may confuse your readers (but not do any immediate harm).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ref in your code.

You should use `ref` only if you intend to change what the variable references to.

Remember that a `List` is a reference type; it's not possible to pass by value